# how to fix grub on a legacy Bios system

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, grub

I have a laptop, which does not have UEFI that had Ubuntu Mate 20.04 as the only os. I installed antix 19 and had no problem with the dual boot, which set antix as the root. After doing apt upgrade in antix, grub got broken and hangs with message normal.mod not found. the entire i386-pc folder on the antix partition is empty. I can boot from antix live usb and run re-install grub which completes without errors. i386-pc remains empty and grub hangs. I copied the contents of i386-pc from my Mate partition to antix and grub this time complained that some symbol was not found. I loaded grub-repair from a live usb and it does not want to fix the system and it complains the system is in legacy mode and I have to enable UEFI. there is nothing to enable UEFI in the bios. the bootinfo dump is at:

[boot-info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GYvmDkPdMZ/)

is this fixable or I should re-install os?

Comment: "that some symbol was not found." - Please be explicit about errors and provide the exact error you received.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the i386-pc files from /usr/lib/grub to /boot/grub/i386-pc and now it boots to a grub menu. it took me to a command prompt, so I have to tinker with it to start the X service, but it boots.